# Magento product images missing in admin but showing in front end

Tags: javascript, image, magento, file-upload, magento-1.9

Using Magento v1.9.2.2 with patches SUPEE-7405 v1, SUPEE-7405 v1.1, SUPEE-8788, SUPEE-9652.

I'm having an issue where none of the images in the product admin are displaying for some reason. It's not just images uploaded since any of the patches have been applied, it's all images, ever uploaded (see image for example).

[Images in admin missing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/llpzR.png)

All the images are still in the media folder, they still exist in the database and they still show up on the frontend.

I've tried various fixes but nothing seems to be coming up trumps, including:

- http://www.blog.magepsycho.com/how-to-fix-the-issue-product-images-missing-in-backend-but-not-in-frontend/
- Checked the Media folders exist and have the correct files
- Checked the permissions on the folders
- media_attribute is correct in the DB
- Renamed the .htaccess file in the media folder
- Flash installed and working
- JS/CSS merging disabled

When inspecting the code in the admin panel I'm getting an "Unexpected Token ','" error in the media_gallery_contentJsObject script

```
//<![CDATA[var media_gallery_contentJsObject = new Product.Gallery('media_gallery_content', , {"cover_image":{"label":"Cover Image ","field":"product[cover_image]"},"image":{"label":"Base Image ","field":"product[image]"},"small_image":{"label":"Small Image ","field":"product[small_image]"},"thumbnail":{"label":"Thumbnail ","field":"product[thumbnail]"}});//]]>
```

Where just after 'media_gallery_content' there is a piece missing.

Comparing this to another store it would appear to be something along the lines of `id_69c186495899f5764a731df5baafee05_UploaderJsObject` that is missing.

Any ideas how to resolve this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Comment: check browser console and logs for more information.